# Is there a way to put Input type 'file' click on icon

Tags: svg, input, icons, tailwind-css

Is there any way of putting input type='file' on svg Icon that I already have in my code example below Download.
I'm using Tailwind CSS.

```
 <td click.delegate="getTenantAgentLicence(agent.agentId)" class="p-6 pb-10 text-left block md:table-cell">
    <!-- <input type="file"/> -->
 <span class="inline-block md:hidden font-bold">Download</span>
    <a class="ml-2 cursor-pointer">
      <img class="h-6 w-6" src="/images/download1.svg">
    </a>
 </td>
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "putting input type='file' on svg Icon"? Would you like a file picker dialog to appear or would you like to download a file when you click the download icon?

Comment: Yes, I would like a file picker dialog to appear when I click on Icon below Download

Answer (score 6):

Put the `<input>` and the `<img>` inside a `<label>`. Clicking the image will be the same as clicking the input element. Then hide the `<input>`.

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="file" class="hidden" name="file1">
  <img class="h-6 w-6" alt="Image here" src="/images/download1.svg">
</label>
```

Comment: tnx, that helped!!